# Concate String to a formula in app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula, automation

I have a values in google sheet and the format is `=+40,-58`. This give me `ERROR!` because the sheet is taking it as formula.
I can manually edit this by adding `' single qoute` before equal sign but when i append qoute using script it append qoute with `ERROR!`.
Tried multiple thing like getting cell type, convert it to string.
Tried set formula method but it appends another equal sign before the cell value

please check the code below

```
if (//my condition){
      
 sheet.getRange(i,col_in+1).setValue("'"+colvalue)
```

I am looking for possible solutions like, how can I get the actual value of the cell from `fx`
or
How can i append a single quote with the cell value instead of appending quote with ERROR.

please see the screenshot of the sheet
[image: Sheet]

Comment: From you question it is not obvious what exactly you are trying to do. What is the value of `colvalue` and what is your desired output in the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Descrition**

Because the formula is giving "#ERROR" you need to getFormula and use setValue

**Script**

```
function test() {
  let cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A6");
  let value = cell.getFormula();
  if( value !== "" ) {
    console.log("formula = "+value);
    cell.setValue("'"+value);
  }
}
```

**Console.log**

```
7:30:31 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:30:31 AM  Info    formula = =+52,-64
7:30:32 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: right!. I also used the replace function to remove the = sign from formula